# ANTLR Grammar incomplete

Tags: antlr

Using this grammar i could find the exponents but the answer I get is in reverse order (example : this is what i am getting : 2 ^ 2 ^ 3 = 64 this is what i am supposed to get : 2 ^ 2 ^ 3 = 2 ^ 8 = 256 ) )

```
grammar SDD1
;

options {
  language = Java;
}
// header for parser related java
@header {
  package com.compiler.tutorial;
}

// header for lexer related java
@lexer::header {
  package com.compiler.tutorial;

}

evaluator returns[int result]
  : expression EOF  {$result = $expression.result;}
  ;   

expression returns[int result]
    : op1=mult {$result = $op1.result;}  
    ( '+' op2=mult {$result = $result + $op2.result;}
    | '-' op2=mult {$result = $result - $op2.result;}
    )*
    ;

mult returns [int result]
  :  op1 = exponent {$result = $op1.result;}
  (  '*' op2=exponent  {$result = $result * $op2.result;}
  |  '/' op2=exponent  {$result = $result / $op2.result;}

  )*
   ;

 exponent returns [int result]
  :  op1=factor {$result = $op1.result;}
     ( '^' op2=factor {$result = (int) Math.pow( $result,$op2.result);}
     )*
  ;



factor returns [int result]
   :  NUMBER  {$result = Integer.parseInt($NUMBER.text); 
                System.out.println ("Number= " + $result);}|
      IDENT  {$result = 0;}|
      '(' expression ')' {$result = $expression.result;}
   ;


fragment LETTER: 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';
IDENT: LETTER( LETTER | DIGIT )*;
NUMBER: DIGIT+;
WS: (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

Comment: 2^2^3 = 64 is itself correct if you evaluate like (2^2)^3 = 64..........perhaps this is because your grammar is not exactly recursive as it should be (the right most expression should be evaluated first???)

Comment: Please don't flag your questions with "urgent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, `2(23)` is 256, not 512 - there is *no* (non-bizarre) associativity that will give you a 512 from that expression :-)

But, if you want right-to-left associativity for your exponential operator, you'll need to modify the `exponent` rule to make it greedy. In other words, allow it to take an `exponent` as a secondary operand (in preference) rather than just a `factor` as it currently stands.

That way, 2^2^3 will indeed evaluate as `2(23)` rather than `(22)3`.

Apologies, I don't know *exactly* how to achieve that with ANTLR, I'm showing my age here but I'm very much a lex/yacc man :-)

But [this PDF](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=antlr%20right%20associativity&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://fmt.cs.utwente.nl/courses/vertalerbouw/sheets/vb-04-antlr-1-4up.pdf&ei=Y5_hTqDCPOOXiAfpueW2BQ&usg=AFQjCNFRMBPPVMej_JMe_SutkxixgDqarA&cad=rja) seems to be what you're after (see slide 35). Basically, you define your item subject to exponentiation `I` (`factor` in your case) and the exponent `E` becomes:

```
E = I  ^ E
  | I
```

Comment: My Requirement is this if suppose 2^4^2 first the exponent 4^2 should be done the result is 16 and then the 2^16 should be done. This is my requirement please help

Comment: @pranith, I understand what you're after, I just had to spend some time translating from `yacc` - see the update.

Comment: @paxdiablo is right... your rule  
 exponent returns [int result]
  :  op1=factor {$result = $op1.result;}
     ( '^' op2=factor {$result = (int) Math.pow( $result,$op2.result);}
     )*
  ;

should split to two rules (something like exp : op1 '^' extEXP; and extEXP : op2 | exp) i don't have the antlr to exactly test but the problem is, you wrote a flatter grammer that avoids greedy approach.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for the reply could you please make changes in the code, i have been trying it but i couldn't figure it out, please help me out.

Comment: @pranith, as stated, I'm only giving you the information needed to fix it, because I know parsers (generally) very well and ANTLR (specifically) not so well. Though it's easy enough to understand the rules you have, I wouldn't be confident coding a rule from scratch. If you want me to _learn_ ANTLR to do _all_ your work for you (rather than just _assist_ you for free), my rates currently run at $100/hour :-)

Comment: @pranithmacha, paxdiablo already did all the hard work for you! :) `E = I  ^ E | I` would be translated to `exponent : factor ('^' exponent)?;` in your case instead of `exponent : factor ('^' factor)*;`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that ^ operator is right associative. And with your current grammar it is defined like left associative. Operators like + , - or * are left associative which is naturally expressed in ANTLR grammar. To express right associativity you need recursive rule. I altered you grammar without touching your actions inside curly braces so it gives the correct parse tree:

```
grammar SDD1
;

options {
  language = Java;
}
// header for parser related java
@header {
  package com.compiler.tutorial;
}

// header for lexer related java
@lexer::header {
  package com.compiler.tutorial;

}

evaluator returns[int result]
  : expression EOF  {$result = $expression.result;}
  ;   

expression returns[int result]
    : op1=mult {$result = $op1.result;}  
    ( '+' op2=mult {$result = $result + $op2.result;}
    | '-' op2=mult {$result = $result - $op2.result;}
    )*
    ;

mult returns [int result]
  :  op1 = exponent {$result = $op1.result;}
  (  '*' op2=exponent  {$result = $result * $op2.result;}
  |  '/' op2=exponent  {$result = $result / $op2.result;}

  )*
   ;

 exponent returns [int result]
  : atom ('^' exponent)?
  ;



atom returns [int result]
   :  NUMBER  {$result = Integer.parseInt($NUMBER.text); 
                System.out.println ("Number= " + $result);}|
      IDENT  {$result = 0;}|
      '(' expression ')' {$result = $expression.result;}
   ;



fragment LETTER: 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';
IDENT: LETTER( LETTER | DIGIT )*;
NUMBER: DIGIT+;
WS: (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

(Notice that the key rule that I added:

```
 exponent returns [int result]
  : atom ('^' exponent)?
  ;
```

doesn't have * behind the right brace, but ?)

So for the input:

```
2^3^4^5
```

you get the following parse tree:

[image]